# Can I import an AWS API definition into Django REST Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I have an API defined in AWS API Gateway, and I would be interested in reusing it in Django REST Framework.

I know AWS's API Gateway has the support for exporting the API as a Swagger file, and I've found that Django REST Framework also supports Swagger, but apparently for documentation purposes only.

Is there a way of importing an AWS API definition into Django, or shall I just start from scratch?

Thanks in advance for all your help.